# subquery and aliases with criteria api

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, subquery, criteria

My question is rather simple: I have this query:

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE t WHERE 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE tbis WHERE  TRUNC(t.date) = TRUNC(tbis.date))>1 ;
```

the field date is a timestamp.

How do I do that with the criteria API?

I have something like this (trunc() is valid with my db server, the sql request works.):

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Myclass.class, "t");
crit.createAlias("t.date", "dateT");

DetachedCriteria subcrit = DetachedCriteria.forclass(MyClass.class, "tbis");
subcrit.createAlias("tbis.date", "dateTbis");

subcrit.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("TRUNC(dateT) = TRUNC(dateTbis)"));

subcrit.setProjection(Projections.count("id"));

crit .add(Subqueries.gt(1, subcrit));
return crit.list();
```

Somehow in the log, i got:
org.hibernate.QueryException: not an association: date

I tried various things, but couldn't get it to work...

I tried:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Myclass.class, "t");

DetachedCriteria subcrit = DetachedCriteria.forclass(MyClass.class, "tbis");

subcrit.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("TRUNC(t.date) = TRUNC(tbis.date)"));

subcrit.setProjection(Projections.count("id"));

crit .add(Subqueries.gt(1, subcrit));

return crit.list();
```

and the SQL condition generated was:

```
TRUNC(t.date) = TRUNC(tbis.date))
```

with the log:

```
18:34:04,461 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000
18:34:04,461 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] ORA-00904: "T"."DATE": invalid identifier

18:34:04,461 WARN  [CriteriaAdapter] list exception: 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

Also

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Myclass.class, "t");

DetachedCriteria subcrit = DetachedCriteria.forclass(MyClass.class, "tbis");

subcrit.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("TRUNC({t}.date) = TRUNC({tbis}.date)"));

subcrit.setProjection(Projections.count("id"));

crit .add(Subqueries.gt(1, subcrit));

return crit.list();
```

with the condition becoming:

```
TRUNC({t}.date) = TRUNC({tbis}.date))
```

and the logs:

```
18:36:28,206 WARN  [TxConnectionManager] Connection error occured: org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager$TxConnectionEventListener@1b3febd3[state=NORMAL mc=org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@4cb16baf handles=1 lastUse=1343284588160 permit=true trackByTx=true mcp=org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$OnePool@7f16f514 context=org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool@3c34353b xaResource=org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@4cb16baf txSync=null]
java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.getNumRows(T4C8Oall.java:1153)
[...]
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
```

Or even:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Myclass.class, "t");

DetachedCriteria subcrit = DetachedCriteria.forclass(MyClass.class, "tbis");

subcrit.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("TRUNC({t.date}) = TRUNC({tbis.date})"));

subcrit.setProjection(Projections.count("id"));

crit .add(Subqueries.gt(1, subcrit));

return crit.list();
```

With the same result as previously.

I think criteria is unable to detect the alias of the subquery... But I have to access  that value, any workaround?

Comment: have you tried `TRUNC( dateT ) = TRUNC( dateTbis )`? note the spaces

Comment: no, but I will, but basically i resigned my self and wrote a 300 long function generating a HQL query.

Comment: It's probably too late now, but `createAlias()` expects a table, you can't alias columns. I'd go ahead with the second snippet but try to escape the reserved word 'date': `TRUNC(t."date")`. Note [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162381/how-do-i-escape-a-reserved-word-in-oracle) with regard to identifier escaping.

Answer (score 0):

First you can try if you shouldn't put the { } only around the alias in the sqlRestriction :

```
subcrit.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("TRUNC({t}.date) = TRUNC({tbis}.date)"));
```

If you don't want to compare a part of the date fields (like the days), but want to see if the entire date fields are equal, you can just let Hibernate do the comparison like this:

```
Restrictions.eq(t.date, tbis.date)
```

If you want to compare a part of a date field, I refer you to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101541/compare-time-part-of-datetime-field-in-hibernate)

Comment: The referenced question just says to use `sqlRestriction`, too? And yeah AFAIK `TRUNC()` returns the date portion of the timestamp.

Comment: well, the first answer used HQL and not sqlRestriction.  But I think I see the problem now. The { } in the sqlRestriction should be only round the alias: like this: subcrit.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("TRUNC({t}.date) = TRUNC({tbis}.date)"));

I will put it in my anwer